# Relation between stationary distribution of a D/M/1 queue and extinction probability in a branching process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, generating-functions, functional-equations, queueing-theory

Let the interarrival times be identically $1$ and the service rate $\mu>1$ (so that $1/\mu<1$). Let $B$ be the distribution of the number of service completions that occur between the arrival of two customers, then
$$b_j:=\mathbb P(B=j) = \int_0^\infty e^{-\mu t}\frac{(\mu t)^j}{j!}\,\mathsf dA(t) = e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^j}{j!}, $$ where $A(t)=\mathsf 1_{[1,\infty)}(t)$ is the distribution function of the interarrival time. Let $\{X_n:n\in\mathbb N_0\}$, where $X_n$ is the number of customers in the system immediately before the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ arrival, then the transition probabilities are given by
$$
P_{ij} = \begin{cases}
b_{j-i+1},& j\geqslant i-1\\
1-\sum_{k=0}^i b_k,& j=0.
\end{cases}
$$
From $\pi=\pi P$ we have
$$\pi_k = \sum_{i=k-1}^\infty \pi_i P_{ik} = \sum_{i=k-1}^\infty \pi_i b_{i+1-k} =\sum_{i=k-1}^\infty \pi_i e^{-\mu} \frac{\mu^{i+1-k}}{(i+1-k)!}, $$ 
which is a countably infinite system of linear equations with no evident solution.

If we assume that $\pi_k = (1-\xi)\xi^k$ for some $\xi\in(0,1)$, then dividing by $(1-\xi)\xi^{k-1}$ yields $$\xi = \sum_{i=k-1}^\infty \xi^{i+1-k} e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^{i+1-k}}{(i+1-k)!}=e^{-\mu}\sum_{j=0}^\infty  \frac{(\mu\xi)^j}{j!} = \exp\left(-(\mu-\mu\xi)\right). $$
Now, this is precisely the equation to determine the extinction probability in a Galton-Watson process with a Poisson offspring distribution. This makes sense intuitively, as this is fundamentally the same process as the D/M/1 queue (conditioned on there being one customer in the system at time zero and killed when the system becomes empty). From here it follows from the Banach fixed point theorem that for an arbitrary $\xi_0\in(0,1)$, the sequence $\xi_{n+1} = \exp(-(\mu-\mu\xi_n))$ satisfies $\lim_{n\to\infty}\xi_n = \xi$, yielding an iterative scheme to compute $\xi$ numerically.

The only problem with this argument is that the assumption $\pi_k=(1-\xi)\xi^k$ is rather arbitrary. It seems like there is a more fundamental relationship between the G/M/1 queue and the Galton-Watson process which one could use to show that the stationary distribution is geometric in form. I am not sure how to make this rigorous though, and would appreciate suggestions or insight into this problem.

Comment: In your exmple, you are talking about $D/M/1$ queue. In the last paragraph you say "It seems like there is a more fundamental relationship between the M/G/1 queue and the Galton-Watson process...". Which queue do you consider, G/M/1 or M/G/1? This is important since in G/M/1 queues the stationary queue-size distribution is always of the form $a(1-a)^k$, $k\ge0$, $0<a<1$ i.e. is always geometric. But in $M/G/1$ it is not.

Comment: I believe I meant to say $G/M/1$ since the post is about $D/M/1$.

Comment: Is the question still of interest? It was in 2016 and now it is 2019.

Comment: @rrv Sure, I am still interested in the answer to this question. It is not of the most pressing priority to me or I would have put a bounty on it. But if you want to take the time to type up an answer that lends some insight into this problem I would appreciate it.

Comment: actually i don't understand what kind of answer it is appropriate to give because "branching processes in queueing theory problems" is quite a broad topic. If you could make your question more specific, maybe then it would be possible for me to answer. Just for the start of the discussion, maybe, this link to the lectures of the professional (prof. V.Vatutin) in this field https://people.bath.ac.uk/ak257/vatutin/vatutin.html may be of help. Lectures IV and V are devoted to branching processes in queueing theory.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I understand that the question is a bit broad. I suppose what I am asking is along the lines of "How can we use the relationship between Galton-Watson processes and D/M/1 queues to show that the stationary distribution is geometric"? Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is too long for comments, so i had to put it here.

After a quick thought i cannot suggest the answer to the question "How can we use the relationship between Galton-Watson processes and D/M/1 queues to show that the stationary distribution is geometric". My guess (which, of course, may be srong) is that it is not possible. At least without additional tricks from queueing theory.

The reason for "no" answer is that the most fundamental question for branching proccesses is the extinction probability. In queueing theoretic setting extinction probability corresponds to the system's busy period. Specifically whether the busy period is finite or not. Even if you know the distribution of the busy period, it is not very clear how the stationary distribution can be found from it. I believe that sometimes it is possible but not in general. For D/M/1 queue i cannot suggest anything.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Specifically that extinction probability corresponds to the system's busy period. I understand that analysis of the busy period can be quite complicated, but it still lends some insight to the relationship between the two types of processes.